# Error in provider Entity Framework MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I try to connect my entity framework in MySQL database but when i connect this error happen

> No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

This is my appConfig for my class library whit entity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
 <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="portallentesContext" connectionString="server=******;User Id=******;password=*********;Persist Security Info=True;database=portallentes"
  providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.6.4.0" />
</DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>

<entityFramework>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.6.4.0" >
  </provider>
</providers>
</entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Did you install the MySQL Connector for .NET?

Comment: yes, i install mySQL Connector

Comment: In the Package Manager Console, try running this command `Install-Package EntityFramework -Pre`

Comment: I already did that too

Comment: What version of Entity Framework do you have?

Comment: I tried with 6.0 and the stable version

Answer (score 0):

copy MySql.Data.Entity.EF5.dll with MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll together to the bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42588773/3652378.

Make sure you have `MySql.Data.dll`referenced in the calling assembly (not only in the class library project, but also in the web application / wcf application which calls the class library).